# Selectize.js Create: validate CREATE input

Tags: jquery, validation, selectize.js

This is my selectize.js function

```
$("#addmobilenumbers").selectize({
    inputClass: 'form-control selectize-input', 
    dropdownParent: "body",persist: false,
    create: true //need to create and allow only digits
});
```

I want only `numeric` (to enter only mobile numbers) input to `create` here with `min/max length`. How can I do it?

Comment: Do not use the jQuery Validate tag unless the question is about the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited tags.

Answer (score 2):

Using `createFilter` and `onInitialize` options

**createFilter**: validates the option before created using given regex

```
/^[0-9]{10}$/ - accepts only numbers between 0-9 of length 10 digits
```

**onInitialize**: event used to set maxlength / restrict input to numbers

```
this.$control_input.prop('maxlength', 10) 

this.$control_input.on('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
})
```

```js
$("#addmobilenumbers").selectize({
  inputClass: 'form-control selectize-input',
  dropdownParent: "body",
  persist: false,
  create: true,
  createFilter: /^[0-9]{10}$/,
  onInitialize: function() {
    this.$control_input.prop('maxlength', 10)

    this.$control_input.on('input', function() {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha512-pF+DNRwavWMukUv/LyzDyDMn8U2uvqYQdJN0Zvilr6DDo/56xPDZdDoyPDYZRSL4aOKO/FGKXTpzDyQJ8je8Qw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.default.min.css" integrity="sha512-H955AcCOE/fUjX4XWkN0FwjCYVV/zioSF6VpUKCcrGdR1Wa8paFWYixWYp85npbnx3i1kZCH4Rm4TRxut2+d5A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<select id="addmobilenumbers" multiple></select>
```

**References**

https://selectize.dev/docs.html#configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can check that condition inside your `create` function . Simply use `$.isNumeric(input)` to check if the value is number and add your min/max length if this condition statisfy create your new option else use `return false;` to prevent any default action.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#addmobilenumbers").selectize({
  inputClass: 'form-control selectize-input',
  dropdownParent: "body",
  persist: false,
  plugins: ['remove_button'],
  create: function(input) {
    console.log($.isNumeric(input), input.length)
    //check if no is numeric ,,and min/max length
    if ($.isNumeric(input) && (input.length > 2 && input.length < 6)) {
      return {
        value: input,
        text: input
      } //create that tags...
    } else {
      console.log("can't add")
      return false; //prevnt default...
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/css/selectize.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="addmobilenumbers">
```